# Internet connection on Linux Mint unstable

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, windows, dual-boot

I bought a computer with Windows 10 installed on it and added Linux Mint to run dual boot. My internet connection is great when I run Windows but very shoddy when I run Mint. Here is my system info

> CPU: Dual Core Intel Pentium 5405U (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max:
>   1600/400/2300 MHz Kernel: 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64 Up: 2d 13h 04m Mem:
>   3420.8/7857.0 MiB (43.5%) Storage: 1.03 TiB (10.3% used) Procs: 222 Shell: bash 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.27

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem might be?

Comment: Your specs fail to mention your network/network settings. Did you have to manually install drivers for your WiFi on Mint? How have you compared your internet speeds?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I didn't have to manually install drivers on Mint.  Can you give me some commands to run to output useful networking info?

Comment: `iwconfig` will display your current NIC settings. You can run speed tests from https://www.speedtest.net/ on both platforms to see just how much of a difference you're getting. If I had to guess, your Linux connection is using 2.4g and Windows 5g.